# Swing worker override process <T,V>

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm trying to override the `process()` method to ensure that some code runs in the EDT. I have made sure that `<T,V>` are matching throughout but it still won't let me override. Here is my code:

```
final SwingWorker<ArrayList<Block>,Integer[]> swingSlaveLabourer = new SwingWorker<ArrayList<Block>, Integer[]>() {

    @Override 
    protected ArrayList<Block> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        blockList.doHeavyWork()..
        Integer [] status = new Integer[2];
        status[0] = 1;
        status[1] = 0;
        this.process(status);
        return blockList;
    }

    @Override //wont allow override
    protected void process (Integer[] chunks){
        progressBar.setValue(chunks[0]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process-java.util.List-) method takes a `List<V>` as argument. It represents all the data chunks that were published. You need to change your code to:

```
@Override
protected void process(List<Integer[]> chunks) {
    // do something
}
```

You should not call directly `process` from the `doInBackground` method. Instead, you should call `publish` to publish each chunk of data.

Refer to the following example taken from the `SwingWorker` Javadoc:

```
class PrimeNumbersTask extends SwingWorker<List<Integer>, Integer> {

     PrimeNumbersTask(JTextArea textArea, int numbersToFind) {
         //initialize
     }

     @Override
     public List<Integer> doInBackground() {
         while (! enough && ! isCancelled()) {
                 number = nextPrimeNumber();
                 publish(number); // each computed number is published
                 setProgress(100 * numbers.size() / numbersToFind); // and progress updated
             }
         }
         return numbers;
     }

     @Override
     protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
         // in the mean while, we print each published value to a textarea
         for (int number : chunks) {
             textArea.append(number + "\n");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: So im passing an arrayList of arrays of Integers? chunks.get(0)[0] seems a little strange. Will that list ever contain more that one element? i feel as though i will always be using chunks.get(0). Isnt that a little redundant? An integer array wouldnt suffice?

Comment: @OrangePot Your design is not correct. See the example I posted.

Comment: So the point of `doInBackground()` is to do heavy work, why is it changing a GUI component (`setProgress()`)?

Comment: @OrangePot It is not changing a GUI component, it is simply updating the progress variable. GUI component should be updated in the EDT, i.e. inside the process method. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20270356/1743880) for the difference between background thread and EDT.